# Как сворачивать меню в мобильной версии сайта ? Прт выборе пункта меню остается развернутым

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
// Burger Menu
var burgerMenu = function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.js-fh5co-nav-toggle', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( $('#ftco-nav').is(':visible') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('in');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active'); 
        }   
    });
};
burgerMenu();

var onePageClick = function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#ftco-nav a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 70
        }, 500, function() {
            // window.location.hash = href;
        });
    });
};

onePageClick();
```